# How to change Edge animate text using php

Tags: php, wordpress, text, adobe-edge

I've created a simple animated text using **Edge Animate** which I could change inside edge animate competition using 
`sym.$("Text").html("NewText");`
How could I use php to manipulate this text and make "NewText" dynamic

I could integrate edge animate in wordpress, but I need to have full control on "NewText", I hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the html code, that edge generates. Then you can access the specific elements of your composition with simple DOM access - getElementByClass probabaly (ofc you have to set the class name in Animate). Then, you can use PHP formulas to change the new text

```
Document.getElementByClass("TextArea").html("<?php echo $_GET['newtext'] ?>");
```

Something like that